# How to redirect find output into file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have tried different bash scripts like this one

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE='C2.DAT'

echo find -name '*.xml' -exec grep -H 'c2 unit' {} \ >> FILE
```

But that is not working.What I want is to redirect the stuff from find to my file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to redirect to `$FILE` instead of `FILE`, and you don't need `echo`. You are also missing a semicolon after the backslash:

```sh
find -name '*.xml' -exec grep -H 'c2 unit' {} \; >> $FILE
```